# How/Can you include/pull a table or data from a .jsp/.txt file into an HTML file for display on a web page?

Tags: asp.net, html, jsp, include

I've very new to web development stuff, so the more details you can include the better! [HTML is down, but JavaScript and more are still being practiced]

I'm making a web page and I want it to display one of two tables of data depending on whether option 1 or option 2 is checked. I've gotten a radio button hide/unhide system done to just show either one table or the other but now I'm stuck on how to populate my tables with data from some files.

- The data I want to put in Table 1 is saved in a .jsp file.
- The data I want to put in Table 2 is also in a .jsp file as well as
  in a plain text file (2 options).
- The files are in the same dir as the .html file

Some notes:

- The files for Table 2 are created from a Perl Script that uses
  the file for Table 1 (.jsp)
- For those unaware, the .jsp files are basically .html files w/ a different file extension it appears (I only know a little about .jsp files from Googling.)
- Using Microsoft IIS; Server Side Technologies: ASP.NET 2.0/3.5/4.0

I know I could just open up those files and put the data into the .html file myself, however besides creating a wall of text in my html file, the data will be changing in the future and I don't want to have to keep editing the HTML file to update it.

So can anyone help me out?
Code examples, tips, points in the right direction, or such is appreciated!

Languages I'm good with: C++, Perl, and just a bit of Java (what I can remember from a class).

Thanks StackOverFlow users!

My Current HTML Code: http://cl1p.net/c4sofmcc/

Feel Free to Edit This Code: http://cl1p.net/c4sofmcced/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`<jsp:include>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html#8828) to "import" a file ("include" is a better word).

E.g. `form.jsp`:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...

<form method="post">
  <label><input type="radio" name="table" value="1" onclick="submit()" ${param.table == '1' ? 'checked' : ''}>Show table 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="table" value="2" onclick="submit()" ${param.table == '2' ? 'checked' : ''}>Show table 2</label>
</form>

<c:if test="${param.table == '1'}">
  <jsp:include page="table1.jsp" />
</c:if>
<c:if test="${param.table == '2'}">
  <jsp:include page="table2.jsp" />
</c:if>
```

Note that you need to ensure that you end up with syntactically valid HTML. So those files should not contain `<html><head><body>` and such. Otherwise you need to use an `<iframe>`. Ask help to http://validator.w3.org if necessary.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help! Though this may be a bit much for my current knowledge, I'm definitely going to look into this solution since it is a nice short one. Also that validator website will be a useful tool for the future. I've added some links to the original post that go to my current .html code if you want to look at that.

Comment: You cannot include a file in HTML. You really need to use a server side view technology like JSP for that. Otherwise you have to use an `<iframe>`. But the iframe target file needs to be a fullworthy HTML file, from `<html>` until with `</html>` with all the `<head>`, `<body>` stuff.

Comment: Ahh alright, I guess that was confusing me a bit. With what I've got, I could use <iframe> then I guess and I'll resort to it if needed. I'd like to try to figure out more however with the server side stuff now though. Looks like I can't find out if JSP will be readily available where I'll be putting my page when its done, but ASP.NET 2,3.5,4 is. Know if that can help me out?

Comment: If JSP contains pure HTML, just rename to `.html`. The IIS server don't understand JSPs.

Comment: Haha yep I am using Microsoft IIS, nice catch. Alright then, I'll make sure to rename them. Thanks for all the help!